# Program a classifier with Weka

Tags: tree, classification, weka

my english is quite bad but i'll try to be clear.
I want to program a classifier (J48 for exemple) with Weka.
In my case, an instance consist of six numbers, all are between 0 and 10 except one which is between 0 and -10.

Exemples : 
1,-3,6,3,6,7 or
1,-4,5,3,7,6 or
2,-4,5,3,8,6

In ARFF :

@ATTRIBUTE attribute1 {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

@ATTRIBUTE attribute2 {0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10}

@ATTRIBUTE attribute3 {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

...

This instances (exemples) are all "good". I would like to known if it's possible to create a classifier. I'll give it a new instance and it could answer (with a percent) if this instance is good or not.
I ask that because i don't know how choose the class index or the outcome varible ...

Answer (score 1):

I am outlining the very basic *how-to-do classification* using Weka.

**The Training File**
You need a training file. Weka considers many different formats as training file (as well, test file). Among them are ARFF (Attribute-Relation File Format) and CSV (Comma Separated Value) format. Let's say we have a training file in ARFF format. A part of the file looks like as follows:

```
@relation pima_diabetes
@attribute 'preg' real
@attribute 'plas' real
@attribute 'pres' real
@attribute 'skin' real
@attribute 'insu' real
@attribute 'mass' real
@attribute 'pedi' real
@attribute 'age' real
@attribute 'class' { tested_negative, tested_positive}
@data
6,148,72,35,0,33.6,0.627,50,tested_positive
1,85,66,29,0,26.6,0.351,31,tested_negative
```

Note that to develop a good learner, you need to have substantial training data. As well, all of your classes should be well-represented in your training data so that the classifier you are going to develop from it has the distinguishing ability for the classes.

**The Test File**
As stated above, the test file can be of many different forms, too. Say, our test file is in ARFF format and a part of our test file is as follows:

```
@attribute 'preg' real
@attribute 'plas' real
@attribute 'pres' real
@attribute 'skin' real
@attribute 'insu' real
@attribute 'mass' real
@attribute 'pedi' real
@attribute 'age' real
@attribute 'class' { tested_negative, tested_positive}
@data
5,116,74,0,0,25.6,0.201,30,?
3,78,50,32,88,31,0.248,26,?
```

Note that the class labels for the test data are with '?' label because the labels are unknown and to be determined by the classifier you develop from training data.

**The Code**
Using the Java API, a trivial method to setup our classifier and build it on the training data and lastly apply it to classify unknown, unlabeled test instances can be as follows:

```
/**
     * Method to build the naive bayes classifier and classify test documents
     */
    public void classify(){
        //setting the classifier--->
        fc = new FilteredClassifier();
        nb = new NaiveBayes();      
        fc.setFilter(filter);
        fc.setClassifier(nb);
        //<---setting of the classifier ends
        //building the classifier--->

        try {
            fc.buildClassifier(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error from Classification.classify(). Cannot build classifier");
        }
        //<---building of the classifier ends
        //Classification--->
        clsLabel = new double[testData.numInstances()]; //holds class label of the test documents
        //for each test document--->
        for (int i = 0; i < testData.numInstances(); i ++){
            try {
                clsLabel[i] = fc.classifyInstance(testData.instance(i));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error from Classification.classify(). Cannot classify instance");
            }
            testData.instance(i).setClassValue(clsLabel[i]);
        }//end for
        //<---classification ends
    }//end method
```

And that's how you classify test instances using Weka!

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rushdi but i'm still missing a important detail. I explain it : I can know the positive instances, i can save them to train my classifier. My problem is i don't know the negative instances. I don't know is i'm clear. I would like classify as positive or not a new instance just in using a list of positive instances.

Comment: You need to teach it the characteristics of negatives. Otherwise it will classify anything as positive.

Comment: So there 're not possibilities to say : all the others features (or mix) are negative. It's right?

Comment: To my knowledge, no I don't think that is possible.